# Expresiones regulares, buscar palabras que contienen determinadas letras

Tags: python, python-3.7

en un dataset con 9 variables donde una de ellas es el nombre de cohete, necesito sacar aquellos cohetes cuya primera palabra empiece por 'S' y acaba por 'k'. Se **deben usar expresiones regulares**. como lo puedo hacer?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
la variable que indica el nombre del cohete la he remarcado en rojo

Comment: ¿Y qué intentaste? Además, ¿ninguno de los de tu ejemplo debería coincidir?

Comment: esos ejemplos son un head del dataset

Comment: Está claro, pero no estás mostrando tu código para saber cómo estás manejando el dataset, tampoco mostrando qué intentaste como para poder enfocar una respuesta sobre tu problema específico, ni tampoco estás mostrando ejemplos válidos que deberían coincidir, cuestión de verificar que realmente debería seguir la regla que mencionaste... Es difícil responder cuando la pregunta es tan vaga... Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta mostrando mucho más detalle del que estás compartiendo hasta ahora

Comment: La expresión regular es "(S\S+k)\S*"

Comment: @CandidMoe eso fallaría con `"XSyykzzz"` ... Además, no estoy tan seguro de que no pueda permitir espacios en el medio del nombre, o si realmente es inicio/fin de una palabra a de todo el string... me parece que hasta que no aclare la pregunta sería intentar adivinar